# How to upload file with selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, upload

I would like to upload a file with selenium using JavaScript button

HTML code :

```
<div class="option optionFile">
<label class="editionFieldMandatory" for="file">File</label>
<input id="file_input" class="file" width="120" type="file" height="30" name="file_input" style="display: none;">
<object id="file_inputUploader" width="120" height="30" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/scripts/external_api/uploadify.swf" style="visibility: visible;">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
<param name="flashvars" value="uploadifyID=file_input&pagepath=/content/&buttonText=Browse&script=/utils/upload_library.php?session_name=j2cnrk8ehssuhhi78gq2pdqoa1&folder=/var/www/BO/IHM/resources/documents/help_manuals&width=120&height=30&wmode=transparent&method=POST&queueSizeLimit=999&simUploadLimit=1&hideButton=true&fileDesc=Documents&fileExt=*.aac; *.aif; *.aiff; *.avi; *.bmp; *.conf; *.csv; *.doc; *.docx; *.dot; *.dotm; *.dotx; *.exe; *.flac; *.gif; *.htm; *.html; *.jpeg; *.jpg; *.log; *.lpcm; *.m2t; *.m2ts; *.mhtml; *.mid; *.mka; *.mkv; *.mov; *.mp3; *.mp4; *.mpeg; *.mpg; *.msi; *.ogg; *.pcm; *.pdf; *.png; *.pot; *.pps; *.ppt; *.pub; *.rar; *.tgz; *.tp; *.ts; *.txt; *.vdx; *.vob; *.vsd; *.vss; *.vst; *.vsx; *.vtx; *.wav; *.wma; *.wmv9; *.xls; *.xlsb; *.xlsm; *.xlsx; *.xml; *.zip&auto=true&sizeLimit=15728640&fileDataName=Filedata">
</object>
<div id="file_inputQueue" class="uploadifyQueue"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have a test but it fails:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='file_input']"));
            elem.sendKeys("C:\test");
```

Tanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your input for `type="file"` has a `display:none` style attached to it.  If you remove it, selenium should be able to interact with it.

Comment: Thanks.I can not change the software I use what I have marked

Comment: @JulienP. , if a user cannot interact with that specific element, neither can Selenium.

Comment: this is a hack, but you can use the following to set the element visible before trying to send keystrokes to it: `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('file_input').setAttribute('Style','display:block');","");`

Comment: @Arran: It looks like the user doesn't interact directly with the input for `type="file"` - I guess the UI is in the flash object so that's what the script should strictly be trying to interact with.

Comment: @vincebowdren your statement is incorrect.  The test he is trying to run specifies the element as being identified by the xpath `//input[@id='file_input']` which is clearly in the html document, not flash.

Comment: @Farlan I think that's why the test is wrong. If the OP wants the webdriver to use the web page in the same way that the user does, it will need to interact with the flash object instead of bypassing it and going direct to the `input` field.

Comment: Thanks. 
@Farlan I have an error : JavascriptExecutor cannot be resolved to a type
The problem is to validate because there is no submit button

Comment: you have to do `import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;` to be able to use `JavascriptExecutor`

Comment: i had already but it's fail too

Comment: what version of FF and Selenium are you using?

Comment: FF 13 and selenium 1.10

Answer (score 0):

It perfectly worked with **JAVA**. So you can try it for JS.

First make sure that the input element is **visible**

Don't click on the browse button, it will trigger an OS level dialogue box and effectively stop your test dead.

Instead you can use:

`driver.findElement(By.id("myUploadElement")).sendKeys("<absolutePathToMyFile>");`

**myUploadElement** is the id of that element (button in this case) and in sendKeys you have to specify the **absolute path** of the content you want to upload (Image,video etc). Selenium will do the rest for you.

Keep in mind that the upload will work only **If the element you send a file should be in the form `<input type="file">`**

Comment: Thanks. I tried driver.findElement(By.id("file_input")).sendKeys("C:\test"); But its not working.

Comment: I wanted to test this script but its not working
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('file_input‌​').setAttribute('Style','display:block');","");
      driver.findElement(By.id("file_input")).sendKeys("C:\test");

Comment: FF 13 and i have selenium 2.0

Comment: Just use the path as **C:\\test\\<file_name>.extension** instead of using **"C:\test"**